# Using setTimout() correctly in Nodejs with a chat bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout

I'm writing an IRC chat bot that answers to commands. My problem is having a cooldown on commands.

My idea is this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  client.on('chat', function (channel,user, message, self) {
    if (message === 'command') {
      // do stuff
    }
  });
}, 5000);
```

The bot reacts everytime a user types in to chat. then it checks if the user typed the command and then it obviously does stuff.

But my Idea here is not working. The bot keeps answering to the command. I just want him to not answer when he already spoke 5 seconds ago.

I tried it with a timer and date.now and stuff but I think if I define a variable like

```
var timer = 100000000000000
```

The variable will have that value all the time and I can't change once because it will be re-defined.

http://www.tmijs.org/docs/ Is the library I am using for my bot

Edit:

```
function doStuff(channel, user, message, self) {
      // do stuff
};


client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
  if (message === 'command') {
    setTimeout( function() {
      client.on('chat', doStuff(channel, user, message,self));
    }, 5000);
    doStuff(channel, user, message, self);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `setTimeout` handler is only setting up a handler for the `chat` event; it's not actually calling the handler. When is the handler called? Every time a `chat` message is sent. So instead, set your timeout when you receive the `chat` event. Something like:

```
var handleMsg = function(channel, user, message, self) {
  if (message === 'command') {
    setTimeout( function() {
      client.once( 'chat', handleMsg );
    }, 5000);
    // do stuff
  }
};

client.once('chat', handleMsg );
```

Comment: I have a question. why do you use client.once ? my bot is somehow only working in my personal channel, not in any others. When using client.on it somehow printed out way too many things and got itself banned

Comment: `client.once()` is just a shortcut for saying "handle this event the next time it fires only" instead of "handle this event every time it fires". It's basically a shortcut for `client.on`, with logic to detach the event handler after the first invocation. See: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener You could use `client.on` here but if so, you'll need to put some logic in the `click` handler to ignore messages that happen before the 5000MS throttle is up, since it will now be called repeatedly.

Comment: okay, but then it makes no sense to me why the command wouldn't work with other channels. How would I do that with the click handler?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `chat` handler, not `click` handler but SO won't let me edit. Just to clarify, you're saying `.on` works with other channels but `.once` doesn't?

Comment: once works only on my channel, but it's not even the same account as the bot. that's why I am confused. Once works perfectly on my channel with 5 second timeouts. On just weirdly spams like 1-5+ answers even if only 1 command was send

Comment: Right. So in your original code, you end up setting up multiple handlers for the `chat` event, because every 5000ms that passes, you call `client.on('chat',...)`, setting up a new duplicate handler for the event. When a single `chat` event is fired under those circumstances, your `chat` handler will be called N times, where N is equal to the number of calls to `client.on('chat',...)` you've made, if that makes sense. N will vary with how much time elapses -- every 5000ms you're adding a *new* event handler, and keeping the old ones in place. Using `.once` sidesteps this.

Comment: yeah that makes sense

Comment: Not to engage in "extended discussion" here or anything, but my previous comment really only applies if you're calling `setTimeout` repeatedly (through code not shown) or using `setInterval`. Essentially, multiple calls to `client.on('chat',...)` can create message spamming unless you have logic to unsubscribe (through `.off` or by using `.once` etc).

Comment: I'm calling client.on a lot in the code, so I can react to other commands.

Comment: The main thing to keep in mind with `.on` when it falls on a repeatedly executed code path is that each call to `.on` is setting up a new event handler. It doesn't magically know to use the existing event handler (if any). In those case you can use `.once`, or, explicitly unsubscribe the handler, or, refactor to calling `.on` one time for each event or event scope at the beginning of your runtime.

Comment: Does my edit make sense? Problem is after 5 seconds it throws an exception or a "TypeError" 'listener must be a function'